# Postgresql query in plpgsql function slows down after several runs

Tags: postgresql

I have a query in a plpgsql function (see below, simplified for clarity) that slows downs after 4 or 5 runs by a factor of about 5 (run time goes from ~700 ms to ~3.5 seconds). If I delete and re-create the function, it starts over: fast for about 5 times and then slow. So, it seems there is something going on with query optimizer, but I cannot get the query plan since it is in the function. If I run the query outside the function with same inputs, it runs fine no matter how many times it is run. If I comment out the 3 left joins, keeping it inside the function, again it runs fine. So, I came to conclude that that it is related to the left joins, but that is about it.

More about the query: it has a `with as` clause, after returning the `data` with about 5000 rows and 40 rows; then, it is self joined 3 times to move some information from rows to columns (this reduces the rows to less than a 1000).

```
create or replace function public.a_function(
-- 5 input parameters here
)

  returns table (a text, b integer, ...) -- about 40 output columns

as $$

declare
...
begin

... --logic to prepare two arrays used in query below: array_a and array_b

   return query
    with data as (                          -- this part of the query returns ~5000 rows and 40 columns
    select d.*
    from public.dashboard_data_view d       -- ~10 million rows in this view
    where d.organization_id = any (array_a) -- array_a: 4 values in int[]
    and d.element_id = any (array_b)        -- array_b: ~10,000 values in int[]
      )
    select c.*, c.value, d.value, r.value, s.value
    from (select * from data where data.population = 'C') c -- this reduces rows down to ~1000
    left join (select * from data where data.population = 'D') d on d.common_id = c.common_id
    left join (select * from data where data.population = 'R') r on r.common_id = c.common_id
    left join (select * from data where data.population = 'S') s on s.common_id = c.common_id
    ;

end

$$ language plpgsql stable;
    ;
```

Platform information: Postgres 9.3 on Ubuntu 14 LTS run on a Vagrant VM with 4 GB of ram and 2 cpus. `shared_buffers` = 1000 MB (1/4th of total) and `work_mem` = 128 MB (development machine, not much going on in parallel).

So, what might be causing the slowing down or what can I do to further investigate?

***Update:*** I pasted the values of array_b into the query as a literal (instead of using a variable), it worked fine. There are about 16K element_id in the view, and filtering about ~10K of them, seems optimizer is deciding to use sequential scan instead of index scan after 5 times. This is my suspicion but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query/optimizer liked the literal for array_b better, I switched to dynamic sql, and fed the variable in as a literal:

```
return query
execute format(
    'with data as (     -- this part of the query returns ~5000 rows and 40 columns
    select d.*
    from public.dashboard_data_view d  -- ~10 million rows in this view
    where d.organization_id = any (%L) -- array_a: 4 values in int[]
    and d.element_id = any (%L)        -- array_b: ~10,000 values in int[]
      )
    select c.*, c.value, d.value, r.value, s.value
    from (select * from data where data.population = ''C'') c -- this reduces rows down to ~1000
    left join (select * from data where data.population = ''D'') d on d.common_id = c.common_id
    left join (select * from data where data.population = ''R'') r on r.common_id = c.common_id
    left join (select * from data where data.population = ''S'') s on s.common_id = c.common_id
    ', array_a, array_b);
```

It worked fine!